# Need to write XML using PHP - how?

Tags: php, xml

I've got this basic code.

```
<chart lowerLimit='0' upperLimit='100' caption='Revenue' subcaption='US $ (1,000s)' numberPrefix='$' numberSuffix='K' showValue='1' >
   <colorRange>
      <color minValue='0' maxValue='50' color='A6A6A6'/>
      <color minValue='50' maxValue='75' color='CCCCCC'/> 
      <color minValue='75' maxValue='100' color='E1E1E1'/> 
   </colorRange> 
   <value>78.9</value>
   <target>80</target>
</chart>
```

it's used from fusionwidgets and there's no documentation on how to write this in PHP.

can anybody advise?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is complete example with [php.net/XMLWriter](http://php.net/XMLWriter) to produce exactly the same XML output like you posted.

```
<?php
$writer = new XMLWriter();  
$writer->openURI('php://output');  
$writer->startDocument('1.0','UTF-8');  
$writer->setIndent(4);   
$writer->startElement('chart');  
   $writer->writeAttribute('lowerLimit', '0');  
   $writer->writeAttribute('upperLimit', '100');  
   $writer->writeAttribute('caption', 'Revenue');  
   $writer->writeAttribute('subcaption', 'US $ (1,000s)');  
   $writer->writeAttribute('numberPrefix', '$');  
   $writer->writeAttribute('numberSuffix', 'K');  
   $writer->writeAttribute('showValue', '1');  
   $writer->startElement('colorRange');  
      $writer->startElement('color');  
         $writer->writeAttribute('minValue', '0');  
         $writer->writeAttribute('maxValue', '50'); 
         $writer->writeAttribute('color', 'A6A6A6'); 
      $writer->endElement();    
      $writer->startElement('color');  
         $writer->writeAttribute('minValue', '50');  
         $writer->writeAttribute('maxValue', '75'); 
         $writer->writeAttribute('color', 'CCCCCC'); 
      $writer->endElement();  
      $writer->startElement('color');  
         $writer->writeAttribute('minValue', '75');  
         $writer->writeAttribute('maxValue', '100'); 
         $writer->writeAttribute('color', 'E1E1E1'); 
      $writer->endElement();  
   $writer->endElement();  
   $writer->writeElement('value','78.9');  
   $writer->writeElement('target','78.9');  
$writer->endElement();  
$writer->endDocument();   
$writer->flush();
?>
```

Comment: Btw. `\XmlWriter::setIndent()` treats its parameter as a bool. It simply enables indentation (using one space) instead of writing the whole XML in one line. See http://php.net/manual/de/function.xmlwriter-set-indent.php.

Answer (score 12):

My favorite way to write XML files is XMLWriter - http://php.net/xmlwriter . It's very powerfull and simple to use.

```
<?php
           $writer = new XMLWriter();  
           $writer->openURI('php://output');   
           $writer->startDocument('1.0','UTF-8');   
           $writer->setIndent(4);   
           $writer->startElement('items');  
           $writer->startElement("main");  
           $writer->writeElement('user_id', 3);  
           $writer->writeElement('msg_count', 11);  
           $writer->endElement();   
           $writer->startElement("msg");  
           $writer->writeAttribute('category', 'test');  
           $writer->endElement();     
           $writer->endElement();   
           $writer->endDocument();   
           $writer->flush(); 
    ?>
```

And that piece of code will produce the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
 <main>
  <user_id>3</user_id>
  <msg_count>11</msg_count>
 </main>
 <msg category="test"/>
</items>
```

Answer (score 4):

See

- [DevZone: XML and PHP](http://devzone.zend.com/article/2387)
- [PHP Manual: XML Manipulation](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php)

Personally, I prefer [DOM](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for working with XML.

You might want to clearify your question. Right now, it's hard to tell what your problem is.

Answer (score 2):

With [**FluidXML**](https://github.com/servo-php/fluidxml) you can generate your XML in this way.

```
$chart = fluidxml('chart');

$chart->attr('lowerLimit', 0)
      ->attr('upperLimit', 100)
      ->attr(...)
      ->add('colorRange')
      ->add('value', 78.9)
      ->add('target', 80)
      ->query('//colorRange')
          ->add('color', ['minValue' => 0, 'maxValue' => 50, ...])
          ->add('color', ['minValue' => 50, 'maxValue' => 75, ...])
          ->add('color', ['minValue' => 75, 'maxValue' => 100, ...]);
```

https://github.com/servo-php/fluidxml

Comment: Pls be informed it not supports PHP 5.x

Comment: FluidXML in the last release supports **PHP 5**.

Comment: Is it compatible with PHP7 also?

Answer (score 1):

SimpleXML, wich is built into PHP is the most simple solution for writing (and parsing) XML. http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: One should note that SimpleXml is simple because it has the least functionality. The other libs are more powerful and offer more control over the XML.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, setIndent sets indentation on and should be used like this:

```
$writer->setIndent(true);
```

if you want to set the indentation size to a different one than the default (2 spaces), you can use setIndentString:

```
$writer->setIndentString("    ");
```