# How to create XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am very beginner to `PHP`. I want to create an `XML` file dynamically and i know how to do that. But here in this case, in the `XML` file, one node should contain an attribute *"name"* with a value from `$_POST` variable. How to write `PHP` code for creating `XML` file which contain a node with attribute *"name"*.

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038535/php-create-new-xml-file-and-write-data-to-it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212982/need-to-write-xml-using-php-how

Comment: Guys,

I got answer from this link. And this is what i needed.
http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createattribute.php

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful for you:

```
<?php
// Send the headers
header('Content-type: text/xml');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-control: private');
header('Expires: -1');
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";

echo '<xml>';

// echo some dynamically generated content here


echo '</xml>';

?>
```

And finally save file with `.php` extension

Answer (score 0):

```
 As a solution to your problem please try executing following example code snippet 

The below code snippet is created on basis of assumption that there is a form for user registration containing fields such as email ,address depicting the procedure for dynamically generation of **xml** content using php

 <?php
     $xmlstring='<xml>';
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
    {
      $xmlstring.='<user>
     <email>'.$POST['email'].'</email>
     <address>'.$_POST['address'].'</address>
     </user>';
    }
    $xmlstring.='</xml>';
    header('Content-type:text/xml');
    echo $xmlstring;
    die;
?>
```