# SimpleXml using huge amounts of RAM when writing file

Tags: php, laravel, out-of-memory, simplexml

I'm running into a problem with my Laravel Application. I have a bunch of data in my Postgres DB that I want to write to an XML file but the command keeps getting killed because it's out of memory and can't allocate any more.

I'm using Laravel 5.6 with PostGreSQL 10 and SimpleXml.

Below is a piece of the code working on building the XML Document.

```
 $startTime = time();

    $feedXml = new SimpleXMLElementExtended('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><products></products>',
        LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);

$storeChannelProducts =
        StoreChannelProduct::where('store_channel_id', $storeChannelId)
                           ->whereNull('channel_data_exclude_reason')
                           ->get();

    ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');

    /*
     * Increase memory and execution time
     */
    ini_set('memory_limit', (384 + min_max((count($storeChannelProducts)) * 2.5, 0, 1728)).'M');
    set_time_limit(min_max((count($storeChannelProducts)) * 0.5, 30, 3600));

    $storeChannelProducts->keyBy('store_channel_product_id');
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($storeChannelProducts as $storeChannelObject) {

        \Log::debug('Feed building after making record ' . $i);
        \Log::debug('Memory usage: '. memory_get_usage());
        \Log::debug('Time since start = '.(time() - $startTime));

        $i++;

        if (gc_enabled()) {
            gc_disable();
        }

        $storeChannelProducts->forget($storeChannelObject->store_channel_product_id);
        unset($storeChannelObject, $feedProduct, $product);
    }

    \Log::debug('End of feed building');
```

In the foreach loop I get the data from my models and use the addChild and addAttribute methods to add the data to my XML file. The collection I loop over consist of about 4600 products.

When I ran the command the terminal gave "Killed!" as output and when I ran it again with the memory usage on a different tab I noticed that after about 1 minute the RAM being used was 1000MB, after about 3 minutes the RAM stabilized around 2370MB and from 5,5 minutes the RAM started increasing again until it crashed a little over the 8 minute mark when it was using 5000MB of RAM for this one command.

I already tried a few things like unsetting all variables that are being reset  on the next iteration of the foreach loop and using gc_disable since I read somewhere that the Garbage Collector could use a lot of RAM to check all XML nodes to see which of them were still active.

I hope someone will be able to give me any insight or advice on how to fix this or decrease the RAM that is being used.

Comment: Out of interest, how much data are you trying to write? As in, you much raw text is coming out of your database? I remember SimpleXML being horribly inefficient with memory because it's converting everything to objects with dozens of fields that don't matter. Also, obligatory JoelOnSoftware "What this means to me is that you can’t use XML if you need performance and have lots of data.": https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/

Comment: You could look into XMLWriter, it's very verbose, but writes out data as you go along.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212982/need-to-write-xml-using-php-how may be helpful.

Comment: @Loek It depends on the products but since we add the descriptions and content of the products as well it can amount to quite a lot. Further annoyance is that this is version 2.0 of a project, the original project handles it just fine which doesn't use Laravel.

Comment: @NigelRen I've seen that around too yea, but to my understanding the difference between SImpleXml and XMLWriter weren't that big. Do you mean that SimpleXml checks the entire file before appending a new child?

Comment: SimpleXML builds the entire data structure in memory.  You write the entire file in one go, XMLWriter writes it as you go along (not sure how fine a control there is) and doesn't build the entire document up first.

Comment: For XMLWriter, you have to have all of the data to write in one go though, you can't build it up in pieces as you can with SimpleXML

Comment: Okay so I would need to manipulate any data beforehand and then create the element and fill it. Is it still possible to use a foreach loop to create all elements or would the elements need to be constructed and filled at the same time?

Comment: Your question currently includes a lot of details that aren't relevant to the problem (SQL access, logging statements, etc), but is missing code that *is* relevant - i.e. the `addChild` and `addAttribute` calls that you think are causing the problem. Could you [edit] to make it more relevant? You might be able to create a [mcve] by using an arbitrary loop like `for($i=0; $i<100000; $i++)` rather than your real data, which would allow for much clearer answers.